# How do I code in a text box to then use later on in a code

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm coding a website where I need to display icons being resized. This is my code for resizing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#icon").animate({
        width: '+=30px',
        height: '+=30px'
    }, 1000);
});

$("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#icon").animate({
        width: '-=#30px',
        height: '-=#30px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Right now it resizes by 30pixels, I need to make a text box where the user can type a number and it will resize it by that number of pixels, but i dont know how to write the code. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<input id="pixInput" />
```

javascript:

access the variable like this:

```
$("#pixInput").val();
```

so you can say

```
width: $("#pixInput").val() + "px";
height: $("#pixInput").val() + "px";
```

maybe some validation should be done too, but this should work.

Comment: did i input it correctly? 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pixInput").val();
    
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $("#icon").animate({
            width: $("#pixInput").val() + "px";
            height: $("#pixInput").val() + "px";
        }, 1000);
    });
    
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        $("#icon").animate({
            width: $("#pixInput").val() - "px";
            height: $("#pixInput").val() - "px";
        }, 1000);
    });                    
});